# What does 'cd ../..' mean in linux?

Tags: directory-structure, cd-command

I am aware that `cd` is used to navigate between files in linux commandline. However, I am not sure what the following, that I came across while trying to replicate something, means:

```
cd ../..
```

It was preceded by

```
bash get_data.sh
```

Please suggest.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`..` means the parent directory.  So `cd ..` means move to the parent directory.  `cd ../..` means move to the parent of the parent directory.

```
$ pwd
/home/Auser/Programming/LFS
$ cd ../..
$ pwd
/home/Auser
```

Comment: Oops! my VMS origins coming through.  Vut then `pwd` = present working directory!

Comment: Beware that in Korn/POSIX-like shells, `cd` interprets `..` differently from any other command. `cd ..`, strips one path component off the end of `$PWD` instead unless you pass the `-P` option. The  difference will be visible when `$PWD` contains symlinks in its path components.